# Python: Calling an API: Getting different place ids when entering the same location differently

Tags: python, json, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

I am really perplexed by this problem I am having with getting the correct place id when I run the code.  The code gives the correct address when I enter the university name, but it does not give me the correct place id.  Given this, I tried running the program by only entering the address of the place and not the university name, and this gave me the correct place id finally.  I confirmed my results with the Google site and have done reverse geocoding.  Why won't it work when I enter the university name???

**Here is the place id I have been looking for, long with the address:**

Place ID: ChIJ18YtYzOJqjsRHEnnXbM0Jjc
University Rd, Mandaiyur, Tamil Nadu 620024, India
The school is called "Madras university."
The link in the code is an API endpoint that has a static subset of the Google Data.

**Here is my code:**

```
import urllib
import json


serviceurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'

while True:
    address = raw_input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1 : break

    url = serviceurl + '?'+ urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address': address})
    print 'Retrieving', url
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'

    try: js = json.loads(str(data))
    except: js = None
    if 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':
        print '==== Failure To Retrieve ===='
        print data
        continue

    print json.dumps(js, indent=4)

    lat = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
    lng = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
    print 'lat',lat,'lng',lng
    location = js['results'][0]['formatted_address']
    print location
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly which query you use that gives the unexpected result, and which query gives the expected result?  Also what do you mean by "correct place id" — what makes the id correct/incorrect for your purposes?

Comment: When running the program, I was getting the exact place id I was being asked to find by entering the exact address of the university when prompted to do so.  However, when I tried running the program another time and entered the name of the university and no other address information, I got a different place id than the previous one.

Comment: I meant correct in terms of what the assignment was exactly asking for as far as the place id.

Comment: I found the exact address of the university from running the code the first time.

Comment: I'm still confused.  You say you want ChIJ18YtYzOJqjsRHEnnXbM0Jjc (which is the Place ID for University Rd), and querying for "University Rd, Mandaiyur, Tamil Nadu 620024, India" finds it.  What's the exact query you are using that gives you the unexpected result?

Comment: I was getting the unexpected result by entering only the university name and not the address.

Answer (score 0):

You are querying the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), which is meant to find postal addresses, not places by name.

That's why you get the correct result only when querying for the address ([University Rd, Mandaiyur, Tamil Nadu 620024, India](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DUniversity%2520Rd%252C%2520Mandaiyur%252C%2520Tamil%2520Nadu%2520620024%252C%2520India)) but not by its name ([Madras university](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3DMadras%2520university)).

If you want to find place by name, [Places API Text Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests) is a better choice.

BTW, the `sensor` parameter is beyond obsolete, just drop it.